# Does google guice provide safe publication garanties for injection mutable dependency via setter?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Sometimes by several reasons, I need to use injection via setter instead of constructor. So in these cases, I can not mark field as final, because field value needs to be changed after construction. As described in JMM, if field is not final, then another thread can see is not completely initialized value of this field. Does guice have any solution to this problem?

In other words, does guice provide guarantees, that method **foo** of class **A** always will see safe published instance of something?

```
public class A {

     // there is no problem with safe publication due to dataSource is final
     private final DataSource dataSource;

     // potential problem with safe publication due to something is not final
     private SomeMutableClass something;

     @Inject
     public A(DataSource dataSource) {
          dataSource = dataSource;
     } 

     @Inject
     public void setSomething(SomeMutableClass something) {
         this.something = something;
     }

     public void foo() {
         // does another thread can observe incompletly initialized value of something? 
         something.doSomething();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, it's about the case where you obtain an instance of `A` on thread 1, and call `a.foo()` on thread 2.  In this case, Guice is equivalent to manually writing

```
Thread 1                     Thread 2
-------------------------------------
A a = new A(dataSource);    | // Thread 2 could observe a.something == null
a.setSomething(something);  | a.foo();
```

**However**, this can only happen if you pass `a` from thread 1 to thread 2 without any form of synchronization.  `synchronized` blocks, thread-safe data structures, etc., have memory ordering guarantees.